# Kafka Spout number of retries

Tags: apache-storm

I am using storm 0.8.2 with ack mechanism and I have a few question regarding fail and retry:

1. Can I limit the number of retries?
2. How can I handle errors on my own? On some errors I want to retry (e.g. the database doesn't respond) and on others I don't want to retry (e.g. there is an error while parsing the tuple).

Comment: This question might benefit from a few more tags so people who could answer it know what it is about.

Comment: @m90: This question is very specific about the Storm-Kafka-Spout. Only people who know Storm, could answer it. (Kafka knowledge alone wouldn't be enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I limit number of retries?

Not a builtin feature. You should implement the logic for that in your Spout.

> How can I control the errors? meaning for some of the errors (ie db is not responding) I want to retry and for other (ie error to parse tuple) I dont want to retry.

I would really recommend to read the whole Storm documentation and particularly, [Guaranteeing Message Processing](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html). Otherwise, I would repost it here.  Once you grasp how Storm handles message processing, it will become really easy to implement.